# Is there a way to apply 3d-like appearance (like bevel) to 2d matplotlib plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, matplotlib-3d

I've been working for a while with the `matplotlib` package in Python, and I know that you can do 2D graphs (usually involving two "dimensions", x and y) or 3D graphs (with functions like `plot3D`). However, I am unable to find documentation about giving a '3D aesthetic' to a 2D plot.

That is, giving the plot a bit of volume, some shadows, etc.

To give an example, let's say I wanted to create a donut chart in `matplotlib`. A first draft could be something like this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Given an array of values 'values' and, 
#optionally, an array of colors 'colors' 
#and an array of labels 'labels':

ax = plt.subplot()
ax.pie(
    x = values,
    labels = labels,
    colors = colors
)

center_circle = plt.Circle((0,0), radius = 0.5, fc = "white")
ax.add_artist(center_circle)
plt.show()
```

[image: Preliminary donut chart with matplotlib]

However, a quick graph with Excel can give a much more appealing result:

[image: Donut chart with Excel. Note the '3d-like textures']

Looking at the documentation of `plt.pie`, I was not able to find anything significant, apart from the parameter `shadow`, which when set to True, gives an underwhelming result:

[image: Matplotlib donut chart with shadow]

Also, I would like to add effect such as the use of bevel (like the 3d-look of the borders of each wedge of the pie) and more style things. How could I improve the look of my graph with `matplotlib`? Is it even possible to accomplish it with this library?

One solution might be using a different library. I am not familiar with `seaborn`, but I know it is also a powerful visualisation library. The same with `plotly`. Does any one of these libraries allow for these kind of customisations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the python wrapper for Google Chart, by gak: https://github.com/gak/pygooglechart

There is a download package in https://pypi.org/project/pygooglechart
You only need to decompress and add a route to the sys.path.

```py
import sys
sys.path.append("/your_path_to_library/pygooglechart-0.4.0")

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import image as mpimg
from pygooglechart import PieChart3D

data = [5.4, 3.9, 31.8, 6.3, 1.8, 38.2, 12.6]
labels = ['Renovable', 'Cogen. Alta Eficiencia', 'CC Gas Natural',
 'Carbón', 'Fuel/Gas',  'Nuclear', 'Otras no renovables']



def pygooglechart_3d_pie(datos, etiquet) :
    chart = PieChart3D(650, 250)    
    chart.add_data(datos)    
    chart.set_pie_labels(etiquet)
    chart.set_colours(['e0440e', 'b6693e', '5caf6e', 
            '8374df', 'd6c7d6', '3394af', '968766'])
    
    # render the image
    chart.download('energia.png')

pygooglechart_3d_pie(data, labes)

image = mpimg.imread("energia.png")
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

3d chart finished: https://i.imgur.com/cfq1nui.png

Answer (score 0):

There are a whole bunch of options on the matplotlib website for pie charts here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/index.html

Matplotlib does not have a built-in option to add a bevel to a 2D pie chart or any other types of charts directly.

But, you could do this (raised shaddow) for a 3d effect:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Pie chart, where the slices will be ordered and plotted counter-clockwise:
labels = 'Frogs', 'Hogs', 'Dogs', 'Logs'
sizes = [15, 30, 45, 10]
explode = (0, 0.1, 0, 0)  # only "explode" the 2nd slice (i.e. 'Hogs')

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.pie(sizes, explode=explode, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%',
        shadow=True, startangle=90)
ax1.axis('equal')  # Equal aspect ratio ensures that pie is drawn as a circle.

plt.show()
```

which give this:

[image]